# ssh hanging then time out

Tags: ssh, networking

I am new to ssh on linux. I have two computers connected on a switch. The first one is  192.168.1.2 and the second is 192.168.1.3. When I use the `ping` command I got a reply and everything is good, but when I use ssh from the frist computer `ssh -v user@192.168.1.3` it gives me,

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.2 [192.168.1.2] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.2 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have ssh installed on both machines. Any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these things:

- Port 22 open and can receive connections
- Make sure OpenSSH or another SSH process is running on the server
- Make sure the SSH configuration file is given the appropriate values

Comment: mmm. `man sshd_config |grep -i appropriate` comes up empty on all my linux boxes, and Solaris too

Comment: @sehe The file isn't located under /etc/ssh/?

Comment: This made me <headdesk/> even while in bed. Sarcasm fail. _What I (mockingly) suggested, is the documentation does not contain info on the appropriate (sic) settings_

Comment: thanks for all,actually port 22 was close so I have inserted this command 
[code] iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT [/code]

Comment: Thanks @norway, I am facing the same problem. How can I Check those things ? I am using a Shared Hosting. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Troubleshooting tips:

- Can you `ssh localhost` on the server?
- Are users allowed? (`AllowUsers` setting)
- Do you bind to the external NIC? (look for `ListenAddress 0.0.0.0` or `ListenAddress ::`)
- Are you running on port 22? (`Port`)

  > - Basically check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.
- **Added**: you can use `netstat -tlpn | grep 22` to find out what programs (if any) are listening on port 22 (*run as root to see the process names*)
  .

Also, consider using an explicit port connect instead of ping (e.g. `nmap -PN remote -p22` or even just `telnet remote 22`)

Answer (score 1):

I know, the question is about the private network, but I had the similar output when I was trying to access a device via the Internet. After googling, I found this question; so, even though, it might not answer the question, others might find my answer helpful. In my case, it turned out that my ISP is blocking the port 22/TCP.

If you are trying to access a device via the Internet, there are basically five possibilities:

1. The network connection might not be going on between the machines. Try pinging the server machine's IP address. If you can't receive any packets, then try checking the network connection on both machines.
2. The SSH server might be misconfigured. Try SSHing into the device locally (from the same device and user to the same device and user) via:

   ```
   ssh localhost
   ```
3. If the server machine is connected to the Internet via a router, the port forwarding might not be configured appropriately. So, check the port forwarding configuration on your router.
4. The local firewall on the server machine might be filtering the incoming connection out. Try allowing incoming connections on the 22/TCP port in your firewall's rules or temporarily disabling firewall altogether.
5. One or both of the ISPs might be filtering the connection out. Try [changing the port on the server](https://uk.godaddy.com/help/changing-the-ssh-port-for-your-linux-server-7306) to something like 2222, restarting the SSH server, and SSHing using the new port. You can specify the port on the client machine via `-p` option in the command like this:

   ```
   ssh USER@HOST -p PORT
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If openssh-server is already installed, could be firewall blocking...assuming you've got ufw enabled.

If you are going from machine 192.168.1.2 to target machine 192.168.1.3.  On target machine do...
Sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.2. And visa versa would be handy

Answer (score 1):

[This is my first answer ever, I ask for constructive criticism if needed. Thanks. :)]

It can be the case that you are *banned* from the target machine, e.g.
because you gave wrong password several times.

Edit `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` on target machine (`192.168.1.3` in your case).
This can be done if you can `ssh` to this machine from another one where
you are not banned.

Complete the line `ignoreip` under `[DEFAULT]` with the IP address of your source machine:

```
[DEFAULT]

ignoreip = 192.168.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if SSH is running on the receiving end. Login to the remote machine and try to ssh to localhost (ssh to the same machine you are on).

```
ssh -v myUserName@localhost
```

This should prompt for your password and then should log you into the same machine. If this does not work, that means that this host does not have SSH enabled. Enabling "remote login" on this server should fix the problem.

If however you were able to ssh from the target server into itself successfully, then the issue is likely somewhere in the middle. Your next thing to check is firewalls on the source host to make sure they are not blocking ssh.

Comment: I call hand-waivy: `Enabling "remote login"` doesn't actually mean anything. Fixing the problem should also enable "remote login", FWIW

Answer (score -1):

Check following things:

1) Run nmap localhost and check port 22 status

2) On your second computer with which you want to connect through ssh, perform ssh localhost